# Safer way of storing post_id in input hidden field

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have to integrate the commenting section in one of the pages of my website. When a user comments on a particular post, the post id is used to identify the post user is commenting into. The post id is in a input hidden field of the corresponding post. Or, I can also use something like data-id attribute(HTML5) in a tag to store id. But is there a safer way to do so? The post id is open and anyone can inspect and change the value of it even from chrome. This is a big security concern. There can be a huge no of posts in that page and I am using ajax call to insert the comment. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `anyone can inspect and change the value of it even from chrome`? You mean developer tools? Firebug?

Comment: yes they can inspect/see it or even change it... but when it submits to the server it is your **server's** responsibility to ensure that the user submitting the response is allowed to respond to the post... and if they change the id to some other post that they don't have permission on, it fails. If they were also allowed to post a reply to the "other" post id... shy of being a weird/silly way to post replies... do you care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, anything can be edited or abused when it comes to JavaScript. In the console, they can send whatever they want as a POST request. There's nothing you can do about it, but you can protect yourself from abuse.

The golden rule is never trust data coming from the user. For example if someone sends you an edit to a post with a given ID, verify that post belongs to the logged in user. If it does, even if they manipulated the ID on the form, it won't matter because it's theirs anyway.

You need to adjust your protection depending on the situation.